# ASP.Net Core web api HttpRequestMessage rewrite

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am re-writing a POST method from ASP.NET Web API to ASP.NET Core I am not sure how to re-write the below code.

ASP.NET Web Api:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post()
{
    var rawds = ConvertByteToArray(Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
    //do something
}
```

ASP.NET Core:

```
public IActionResult Post()
{
    var rawds = ConvertByteToArray(Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
    //do something
}
```

Comment: First of all, it's hardly ever necessary to read `Request.Content` in ASP.NET (both Web API and Core), so this looks wrong with the provided code already. Second, what doesn't work with the code you posted?

Comment: if you need the request stream, just get it using `Request.Body`.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to achieve.